# Jquery list show / hide 5 items onclick

Tags: jquery, list, sorting, hide, show

i have a jquery problem with lists.
I have a big list and i want when a link is clicked;
each time the next 5 items of that list will be shown and the previous items hide.

How can i do this?

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
<li>11</li>
<li>12</li>
<li>13</li>
<li>14</li>
<li>15</li>
```

Onload this should be shown:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

when clicked on "next"

```
6
7
8
9
10
```

when clicked on "next"

```
11
12
13
14
15
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you have problems with? What have you tried so far? Please post your jQuery code too.

Comment: Instead of posting the requirements, could you please post the relevant piece of code you're dealing with ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an option:
http://jsfiddle.net/JQq5n/

Don't know how/if you plan to show the previous items so I've left that out

Answer (score 8):

This solution is shorter, and also works bidirectional (`Previous` and `Next`).
**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JQq5n/61/**

```
$('ul li:gt(4)').hide();

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var first = $('ul').children('li:visible:first');
    first.prevAll(':lt(5)').show();
    first.prev().nextAll().hide()
});

$('.next').click(function() {
    var last = $('ul').children('li:visible:last');
    last.nextAll(':lt(5)').show();
    last.next().prevAll().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is untested code, but I'm thinking it'll get you going in the right direction..

```
var currentShowingSet = 1;

$('#next').click(function() { 

    // Hide all.
    $('ul li').hide();

    // increment currently showing set of items.
    currentShowingSet++;

    // show the next 5 children of the list.
    for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        $('ul li:nth-child(' + (currentShowingSet * i) + ')').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it seems having some working issue... I believe there is something missing...