# Hide Next/Prev Link from function

Tags: jquery, list, hide, show

I'm working with a previous post trying to limit the number of list items using jquery and I need to hide the next/previous links when it reaches the end of the list. I'm sure this is a simple addition, but I can't seem to find a solution to augment this function.

Here's the function: (copied from [Jquery list show / hide 5 items onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635441/jquery-list-show-hide-5-items-onclick))

```
$('ul li:gt(4)').hide();

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var first = $('ul').children('li:visible:first');
    first.prevAll(':lt(5)').show();
    first.prev().nextAll().hide()
});

$('.next').click(function() {
    var last = $('ul').children('li:visible:last');
    last.nextAll(':lt(5)').show();
    last.next().prevAll().hide();
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JQq5n/61/

I just need help hiding the next/prev links when it's preached the end of the list. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Shouldn't you only hide next when it is at the end of the list? if you hide prev then how does the user go back?

Comment: Try my answer. It hides both next and prev with one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RNrgE/1/

```
$('ul li:gt(4)').hide();

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var first = $('ul').children('li:visible:first');
    first.prevAll(':lt(5)').show();
    if(first.prevAll().length < 6){
         $('.prev').hide();   
    }
    first.prev().nextAll().hide();
    $('.next').show(); //Now there must be items below so make sure the next link is visible
});

$('.next').click(function() {
    var last = $('ul').children('li:visible:last');
    last.nextAll(':lt(5)').show();
    if(last.nextAll().length < 6){ //We've reached the end so hide the links
        $('.next').hide();
    }
    $('.prev').show(); //Now there must be items above so make sure the prev link is visible
    last.next().prevAll().hide(); 
});
```

Comment: if you hiding both prev and next then the show next and prev would never trigger

Comment: You should try this code in fiddle, it looks different then it should

Comment: It seems I can't edit my answer anymore, but the correct, working solution is available at http://jsfiddle.net/RNrgE/1/. @Huangism, can you possibly update code and fiddle link?

Answer (score 0):

try this [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZYtP/5/).

It hides, **prev** and **next** links if no remaining items to show in both next and prev cases.

```
function doShowNextPrev(){
    if($('ul li:first').is(':visible'))
        $('.prev').hide();
    else
        $('.prev').show();    

    if($('ul li:last').is(':visible'))
        $('.next').hide();
    else
        $('.next').show();    
}
```

Just added following fun to check whether or not show next and prev links. Above fun needs to be called on doReady and whenever next and prev are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li:gt(4)').hide();

updateButtons();

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var first = $('ul').children('li:visible:first');
    first.prevAll(':lt(5)').show();
    first.prev().nextAll().hide();
    updateButtons();    
});

$('.next').click(function() {
    var last = $('ul').children('li:visible:last');
    last.nextAll(':lt(5)').show();
    last.next().prevAll().hide();
    updateButtons();    
});

function updateButtons () {
    var list$ = $('ul');
    $('.prev, .next').show();
    if (list$.children('li:first').is(':visible')) {
        $('.prev').hide();
    }
    if (list$.children('li:last').is(':visible')) {
        $('.next').hide();
    }
}
```